# Stone-Čech compactification

Tags: lo.logic, gn.general-topology, stone-cech-compactification

1. Is every hyperstonean space a Stone-Čech compactification of a discrete space?
2. Is there a closed subset of Stone-Čech boundary that is extremally disconnected?

Comment: $\beta\omega-\omega$ is not extremally disconnected. Indeed the Boolean algebra $2^\omega/2^{(\omega)}$ is not complete.

Comment: Is every proper closed subset of \beta \omega -\omega not extremally disconnected?

Comment: As for 1, hyperstonean space need not have isolated points.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  As we know the abelian von Neumann algebra $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})=C(X)$. Is $X$ a Stone-Čech compactification of a discrete space?

Answer (score 5):

As for Q1, the answer is no. As remarked by Narutaka, the hyperstonean cover of $[0,1]$ does not have isolated points ([Corollary 2.22](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/dissertationes-mathematicae/all/481/0/88120/second-duals-of-measure-algebras)) and all points of a discrete space $\Gamma$ are isolated in $\beta \Gamma$. Hyperstonean spaces can be way more wilder; all relevant information can be found in the book *[Banach spaces of continuous functions as dual spaces](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-32349-7)* by Dales, Dashiell, Lau, and Strauss.

As for Q2, if you mean $\beta \mathbb N \setminus \mathbb N$, then yes, there are lots of copies of $\beta \mathbb N$ therein.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As we know the abelian von Neumann algebra $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{T})=C(X)$. Is X a Stone-Čech compactification of a discrete space?

Comment: @Sherlok, no, it is not as it does not have isolated points. This is deducible from the linked result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  Silov boundary of $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})$ is a retraction of a Stone-Čech compactification of a discrete space. Does Silov boundary of $H^{\infty}(\mathbb{D})$ contains isolated points?